# How to use arbitrary data to select an array for R class in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am new to Java and Android and come from PHP background. I am trying to display a list view based on arbitrary data received from a previous activity. This the code that I am using:

```
String[] chapter_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.view_chapter);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.view_surah, chapter_array));
```

How do I change the "view_chapter" in R.array.view_chapter to make it populate the list from the data received from the last activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to write a custom `ListAdapter` that pulls the data out of the Intent passed to the new activity (i.e. `getIntent().getExtras()`) and feed that data into your custom `ListAdapter`.

The Android developer docs have a [good sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List4.html) on how to write a `ListAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the same question still stands. The data received from the last activity changed depends on user selection. So how do i make the R.array.(intent_received) changes based on the selection?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Erich's answer you could simply have the previous activity pass a string in CSV form and do `String[] chapter_array = getIntent().getExtras().split(',');` or something similar to that